# javascript pushing element at the beginning of an array

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects and I'd like to push an element at the beginning of the of the array.

I have this:

```
var TheArray = TheObjects.Array;
TheArray.push(TheNewObject);
```

It's adding `TheNewObject` at the end. Do I need to create a new array, add `TheNewObject` to it and then loop through `TheArray` and add each element the to the array?

Answer (score 1287, accepted):

Use [`unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift), which modifies the existing array by adding the arguments to the beginning:

```
TheArray.unshift(TheNewObject);
```

Answer (score 173):

Use `.unshift()` to add to the beginning of an array.

```
TheArray.unshift(TheNewObject);
```

See MDN for [doc on `unshift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) and here for [doc on other array methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

FYI, just like there's `.push()` and `.pop()` for the end of the array, there's `.shift()` and `.unshift()` for the beginning of the array.

Answer (score 73):

For an uglier version of `unshift` use `splice`:

```
TheArray.splice(0, 0, TheNewObject);
```

Comment: why would you do that?

Comment: Well as a programmer it is always very important to have options, sometimes the easy solutions dont always work in certain situations, and splice is a good way to remove items from arrays, so knowing how to insert with it is useful

Comment: in terms of readability, splice is more self-explanitory to me. `unshift` sounds like I'm removing something from an array (even though I'm not). `splice` sounds more like I'm merging 2 things together

Comment: What about performance?

Comment: @Cacoon: The only use I can think of for "splice" in this instance is if the program is deciding at runtime whether or not to insert the array at the beginning. For example,

Comment: let spliceIndex = insert ? 0 : -1;
TheArray.splice(spliceIndex,0,TheNewObject)